# The first item in the gridview does not display selected state

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview as follows

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:numColumns="3" />
```

This is in the oncreate

```
gridView = (GridView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(defaultItemClickListener);
gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(defaultItemLongClickListener);
```

This is my adapter getView method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Viewholder vh = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        vh = new Viewholder();
        vh.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
            vh.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
    }
            Item item = getItem(position);
       if (item.getIcon() != null) {
        vh.icon.setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());
    }
    if (item.getTitle() != null) {
        vh.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

The Image drawable of the icon is a StateListDrawable defined by this selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_settings_mail" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_settings_mail_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_settings_mail" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_settings_mail"></item>

</selector>
```

The gridview , when i click on any item (i have 6 items in the given gridview) that is not at position 0, the selector works just fine

when i click on position 0 cell , the selector does not work.

What is so special about the 0 position cell, why doesnt my selector work on it ?

xml of 1 item

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:text="Chart"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: maybe the `item.getIcon() != null` statement doesn't happen for item in position 0. Means, the icon of this item is `null`?

Comment: does onItemClick fires when you touch position 0?

Comment: @sromku the icon is displayed, so the "normal" state of it does get assigned

Comment: @LenaBru unless you have `@drawable/ic_action_settings_mail` defined in you layout xml of the resource view that you inflate

Comment: its not defined there, see the layout of my xml  in my edited post

Comment: I have the same issue, and I cant find the solution. Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to list gridview data

Step 1 :layout

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dip"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dip"
    />
```

Step 2 : onCreateView

```
   GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
```

Step 3: SetAdapter in onCreateView

```
 Adapter mGridAdapter = new Adapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mUsers, this);
    gridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);
```

Step 4: Assign value need to list eg:mUsers //Sample

```
  Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  tempMap.put(Reference.TITLE, UserTitle);
  mUsers.put(Integer.toString(mUsers.size()), tempMap);
```

Step 5: In adapter

```
private Context mContext;
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> mData = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

public TapAdapter(Context context, Map<String, Map<String, String>> catalog, Fragment fragment) {

    mContext = context;
    mData = catalog;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_user_list, null);


        holder.sTxtTitle = mViewUtils.createTextView(convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_Username), true);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    if (data != null) {

        convertView.setTag(R.string.USER_NAME, data.get(Reference.TAP_USER_TITLE));


        holder.sTxtTitle.setText(data.get(Reference.TAP_USER_TITLE));


    }

    return convertView;

}


    Map<String, String> data = mData.get(Integer.toString(position));

    if (data != null) {
       convertView.setTag(R.string.USER_NAME, data.get(Reference.TAP_USER_TITLE));
       holder.sTapWrapper.setTag(R.string.USER_NAME,data.get(Reference.TAP_USER_TITLE));
    }
}
```

Comment: your getview will fall on null pointer exception, because you set convertview's tag without checking if its null

Comment: How will it fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

As much as i remember i had similar problem with ListView once..
getView is called a few times and caches the data, and in case you don't have else sometimes it can cause weird things. So i wrote in comment the else you are missing.
I am not sure but has much as i understand `item.getIcon()` will set the selector that you have created.. Please try this and update me

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Viewholder vh = null;
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    vh = new Viewholder();
    vh.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
        vh.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    convertView.setTag(vh);
} else {
    vh = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
}
        Item item = getItem(position);
if (item.getIcon() != null) {
    vh.icon.setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());
} else {
   ///Put you else code here
}
if (item.getTitle() != null) {
    vh.title.setText(item.getTitle());
}  else {
   ///Put you else code here
}

return convertView;
}
```